# IndexError: string index out of range for if statments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make it so that my program will break up a sentence into a list

```
alpha =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
def PARSE(inpu):     #Parse and remove symbols
PARSE = list()
d = 0

intv = 0
output = 0
for i in range (len(inpu)):
    intv = intv + 1
    if inpu[intv] in alpha:
        output = output, inpu[intv]
intv = 0
LI1 = 1
LI2 = 1
while len[output] != LI1 - 1:
    PARSE.append("")
    while not len[output] - 1 < LI1 or not output[LI1] == '':
        PARSE[LI2 - 1] = PARSE[LI2] + output[LI1]
        LI1 = LI1 + 1
        last = last + 1
        LI1 = LI1 + 1
        LI2 = LI2 + 1
PARSE[last] = PARSE[last] + output[LI1 - 1]
done = 1
```

But I get this error mesage

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

on

```
if inpu[intv] in alpha:
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to filter out all punctuation and symbols, try this:

```
import string

def Parse(inpu)

   return ''.join(i for i in inpu if i.lower() in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a built-in method `isalpha()`:

```
for i in range(len(inpu)):
    if inpu[i].isalpha():
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand for your alpha:

```
import string

alpha = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a second index `intv` whose value is `i+1` and gets out of range.
Change:

```
for i in range (len(inpu)):
    intv = intv + 1
    if inpu[intv] in alpha:
```

by:

```
for i in range (len(inpu)):
    if inpu[i] in alpha:
```